# Simple working Spring MVC / Maven configuration

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, configuration, theory

I’ve been trying to set up a Spring MVC application from scratch, using Maven, in IntelliJ Idea. I know there are probably some nice Archetypes that can do this for you, but I really want to understand what’s going on. Here’s what I want to do:

Create a simple web application that shows displays “Hello World” under https://localhost:8080/, using an embedded Tomcat (with the Maven plugin). So, one controller, one request mapping, and one template. I’ve been able to get the spring application to boot (the Spring logo appears in the console) and Tomcat seems to run as well (the site responds). The problem is, I haven’t been able to get the request to map to my RequestMap method in my Controller. I’m quite sure that the controller isn’t the problem, but that it’s some configuration/setup issue.

Here’s the thing: I’ve been looking at tutorials, StackOverflow, Spring documentation, etc. for hours now, but I haven’t found a source that really explains how to configure a Spring MVC Maven project. Everyone seems to have a different opinion on what XML files you need, what they should be named, and where they should be located. The consensus seems to be that you need a web.xml file in a folder named WEB-INF, but even there, everyone has a different opinion on where that folder should go. I appreciate that there are multiple different ways to do this, and that there’s no “right” way, but in my experience, there are definitely many “wrong” ways =).

My question right now isn’t necessarily how to get my current project running (I don’t mind starting over), but what kinds of config files are out there (web, spring, app-config, servlet, …), what they do, which ones you need, where they need to go, what they should be named, how they connect, etc. Some people also use the Maven Compiler plugin, and others don’t, and nobody says why :D. Essentially: How do I let Spring know where to find controllers, templates, etc., and how to run and deploy all of this on the embedded Tomcat. I would like to find a source that explains the entire core-ecosystem of Spring MVC in a unified way. I have found many sources that provide “how-to” tutorials, but with little to no explanation (like “add the following servlet.xml file to your WEB-INF folder”). So, if your setup slightly differs from the tutorial (e.g. because you are using IntelliJ instead of Eclipse, Tomcat instead of Jetty, embedded Tomcat, a slightly different folder structure) nothing works, and, most importantly, you have no clue why.

Has anyone learned these setup-basics with anything better than copy/pasting or trial & error? :D

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to start is by using Spring Boot. Go to following link:

[Spring initializr](https://start.spring.io)

Choose "Web" for "Selected Dependencise" and click "Generate Project". Download of maven project should start after that. Then import that project in IntelliJ IDEA as a Maven project. And that is a good starting point. You'll get main class that you can run and embeded Tomcat will start at 8080 port. Than you can add some controller, template etc...

Also good [guides](https://spring.io/guides)

Comment: Okay thanks. I've tried Spring Boot and it works well, but to be honest, it is very hard to understand what's going on in the background, since it configures everything for you =). But I will give the guides another look.